# Labview matrix confusion

Tags: labview

May be my question sounds very basic but i have a confusion. I want to represent matrix in the following form in the block diagram of the labVIEW, not front panel. How can i make such matrices using block diagram not by front panel??? Can someone help me?

[cluster of matrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtnPb.png)

Comment: Better search a bit before posting here. 
http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvhowto/creating_matrix_ctrl_ind/

Comment: yes i did already but i could not find my answer. They all are related to front panel, but i need it in block diagram.

Comment: https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvconcepts/using_matrices/

Comment: http://www.ni.com/white-paper/7571/en/

Answer (score 1):

These are the simple steps to achieve your request:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can access any matrix using "**unbundle by name**"

[image]

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful